# Compute this limit $\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin(x^2+\frac{1}{x})-\sin\frac{1}{x}}{x}$ using L'Hôpital's rule

Tags: calculus, limits

[I have asked this problem before](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/423938/how-can-evaluate-lim-x-to0-frac-sinx2-frac1x-sin-frac1xx#comment905843_423938), but I can't understand the explanation, I couldn't understand how the sin multiply for cos, and too multiply for A + and - B: $$\sin(A)-\sin(B)=2\sin\left(\frac{A-B}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{A+B}{2}\right)$$ and I don't understand in this step how/why the $A-B$ and $A+B$ was replaced by $\frac{x^2}{2}$ and $\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac{1}{x}$ :
$$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{\sin\left(x^2+\frac1x\right)-\sin\left(\frac1x\right)}{x}= \lim_{x\to0}\frac{2\sin\left(\frac{x^2}{2}\right)\cos\left(\frac{x^2}{2}+\frac1x\right)}{x}.$$

Comment: If you have asked this problem before, maybe you could give the link to that previous question?

Comment: @user73276:i cant use  L'hôpital's rule because $\lim_{x\to0}{\sin(x^2+\frac{1}{x})-\sin\frac{1}{x}}\neq0$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**:its easy to prove  $$\sin(x+y)+\sin(x-y)=2\sin(x)\cos(y)$$
then put $y=\frac{A+B}{2}$,$x=\frac{A-B}{2}$
$$ \sin(x)\sim x$$  $$\ cosx\sim1-\frac{x^2}{2}$$ because $$\lim_{x\to0}\frac{sinx}{x}=\lim_{x\to0}\frac{cosx}{1-\frac{x^2}{2}}=1$$

Answer (score 2):

It's easier if you use the plain old addition formula:

$$\sin{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x}\right)}  = \cos{x^2}\, \sin{\frac{1}{x}} +  \sin{x^2} \,\cos{\frac{1}{x}}$$

which behaves as

$$\left(1-\frac12 x^2\right) \sin{\frac{1}{x}} + x^2 \cos{\frac{1}{x}}$$

so that

$$\frac{\sin{\left(x^2+\frac{1}{x}\right)} - \sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{x} \sim \frac{x^2 \cos{\frac{1}{x}} - (1/2)x^2 \sin{\frac{1}{x}}}{x}$$

which goes to zero as $x \to 0$.